# Position text inside multiple polygons SVG

Tags: html, svg, path, polygon

This is the part of the map, where I need several polygons with some multi-line text in each. Is this possible without manually positioning each text element?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="estate-masterplan" width="3010" height="1897">
  <g fill="#D8D8D8" fill-rule="evenodd" transform="translate(-0.000000, 0.000000)">
    <rect width="3010" height="1897"/>
    <polygon stroke="#000" points="339 1265.26 351.666 1240.334 390.334 1227.223 408.334 1278.111 365 1294.111 346.556 1286.778"/>
    <text font-size="15" dy="0">
      <tspan x="0" dy=".6em">tspan line 1</tspan>
      <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">tspan line 2</tspan>
      <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">tspan line 3</tspan>
    </text>
    <polygon stroke="#000" points="390.334 1227.223 445.444 1209.89 463.307 1265.26 408.334 1278.111"/>
    <text font-size="15" dy="0">
      <tspan x="0" dy=".6em">tspan line 1</tspan>
      <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">tspan line 2</tspan>
      <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">tspan line 3</tspan>
    </text>
    <polygon stroke="#000" points="445.444 1209.89 502.777 1199 509 1258.334 493.765 1258.334 463.307 1265.26"/>
    <text font-size="15" dy="0">
      <tspan x="0" dy=".6em">tspan line 1</tspan>
      <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">tspan line 2</tspan>
      <tspan x="0" dy="1.2em">tspan line 3</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.  SVG does not have any automatic layout like HTML does.  You have to position the text yourself.

You could use Javascript to calculate the centre of your polygons, and position the text that way.  Also, assuming you are in a browser, you can use a `<foreignObject>` element to embed some HTML in the SVG.  But otherwise, deciding where each piece of text goes is all your responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

I've changed your svg mostly reorganising the elements. 
The estate_masterplan size is different but you can change it to what you want.

I'm using javascript to calculate the position of every `<tspan>`. please read the comments in the code. I hope it helps.

```js
let estate_masterplan = document.querySelector("#estate_masterplan")
// all the groups
let gs = Array.from(estate_masterplan.querySelectorAll("g"));
// all the polygons
let ps = Array.from(estate_masterplan.querySelectorAll("polygon"));

// for each group
gs.forEach((g,i) =>{
  let bb = ps[i].getBBox();// calculate the bounding box
 
  // the center
  let c = {x: bb.x + bb.width/2,
           y: bb.y + bb.height/2}
  
  let t = g.querySelector("text");// the text
  t.setAttributeNS(null, "x", c.x )
  t.setAttributeNS(null, "y", c.y )
  let ts = t.querySelectorAll("tspan")// the tspan-s
  let ts1l = ts[0].getComputedTextLength();// the first span length
 
  ts[1].setAttributeNS(null, "dx", -ts1l )
  ts[2].setAttributeNS(null, "dx", -ts1l )
})
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
text{font-size:9px;dominant-baseline:middle; text-anchor:middle;}

polygon{ fill:#D8D8D8;stroke:black;}
```

```html
<svg id="estate_masterplan" viewBox="300 1190 270 120">
  <g>
    <polygon points="339 1265.26 351.666 1240.334 390.334 1227.223 408.334 1278.111 365 1294.111 346.556 1286.778"/>
    <text><tspan dy="-9">tspan line 1</tspan><tspan dy="11">tspan line 2</tspan><tspan dy="11">tspan line 3</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  
  <g>
    <polygon  points="390.334 1227.223 445.444 1209.89 463.307 1265.26 408.334 1278.111"/>
    <text><tspan dy="-9">tspan line 1</tspan><tspan  dy="11">tspan line 2</tspan><tspan dy="11">tspan line 3</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
  
  <g>  
    <polygon points="445.444 1209.89 502.777 1199 509 1258.334 493.765 1258.334 463.307 1265.26"/>
    <text><tspan dy="-9">tspan line 1</tspan><tspan  dy="11">tspan line 2</tspan><tspan dy="11">tspan line 3</tspan>
    </text>
   </g>

</svg>
```